# jQuery code not called after window.location.replace( url )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that after clicking on a link ('#versionPageFromProdLink'), will redirect the page to the index page. The index page has  that contains the content. I want to hide this after the page is redirected and show the next div that i have ().

The page is redirected however the jQuery function after the window.location.replace( url  ); line is not called.

How will I be able to redirect and call the jQuery after page redirection?

Code:

```
 jQuery( '#versionPageFrmProdLink').click( function(){
    window.location.replace( url  );

    // jQuery code below is not called, <div id="versionMainContent"> is not hidden 
  jQuery(".versionMainContent").hide("fast", function(){
    jQuery( ".versionProductContent" ).show();
  });   

 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, the location.replace means the code "after" it won't execute.  What you will need to do, is append a hash "index.html#divCode" or some such (you could also use a query string in this case) and then detect that onload / on document-ready for the index page, then update the hide/show status there.

Comment: on the index page, use if(window.location.href.indexOf("#divCode") != -1) {... (in this example ) as the condition to run your swap code

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally impossible.

Once you navigate to a different page, the previous page, including all of its Javascript, is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You must handle the secondary executation after the redirect in the page you are redirecting to.

Example:

**Page 1**

```
jQuery( '#versionPageFrmProdLink').click( function(){ 
  window.location.replace( url  ); 
}
```

Note during redirection you can pass a query string in the URL to check a condition in the next page.

**Page 2**

Now that you redirected to the next page. You can place a document.ready function and run what is needed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".versionMainContent").hide("fast", function(){ 
    jQuery( ".versionProductContent" ).show(); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your design is the problem.  Redirecting stops the flow of execution.  You can use ajax to make a server call and continue execution.

Or, if you prefer you can perform a redirect and pass a URL parameter like ?hideVersionMainContent=true and perform the hide server side.

There are other ways to accomplish the task, but that should give you a few ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The code after your `location.replace` operates on the page that you're *leaving* (if it is ever run at all; changing the `location` navigates away from the page and may well terminate your code right there).

You'll need to pass the information to display to the new page, and have code on the *new* page fill in the stats. There are lots of ways to do that:

- On the query string
- Via [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) (`sessionStorage` would probably make sense)
- Cookies (but don't, it's not what they're for)